# Filter array column in Pandas dataframe --Pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pandas dataframe like this where run_dates column is array of string dates

```
JobId  run_dates
1      ['2020-04-03','2020-04-02','2020-04-01']
2      ['2020-04-05','2020-04-07']
3      ['2020-03-25','2020-04-01']
4      ['2020-04-06','2020-02-09','2020-02-11']
```

Im trying to find all job ids which ran between `2020-04-05 to 2020-04-11` even atleast there is one date in the array which falls under this window

So below is what i have tried i created an string array for the date range 2020-04-05 to 2020-04-11

```
input_runs_array=['2020-04-05','2020-04-06','2020-04-07','2020-04-08','2020-04-09','2020-04-10','2020-04-11']

search_array = array_sort(array(*map(lambda e: lit(e), input_runs_array)))
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(pandaDf) //convert above pandaDf to sparkDF
final_df=spark_df.where(array_sort(array_intersect(spark_df['run_dates'], search_array)) == spark_df['run_dates'])
display(final_df)


output:

OK

Expected output:

    JobId  run_dates
    2      ['2020-04-05','2020-04-07']
    4      ['2020-04-06','2020-02-09','2020-02-11']
```

Comment: try: `df.filter("!exists(run_dates, x ->  x > '2020-04-11' OR x < '2020-04-05')").show()`

Comment: @jxc this doesnt work if there is jobid with run_dates ['2020-04-06','2020-02-09','2020-02-11'],its not returning that jobId though there is a run_date falls within the window

Comment: `2020-02-09` and `2020-02-09` are out of range, right? if you want to keep in case any  record is in the range, then `df.filter("exists(run_dates, x -> x between '2020-04-05' AND '2020-04-11')").show()`